# How can i add header links next to language switcher or Left side

Tags: magento2.3.1, toplinks, headerlink

I need to add some custom links on header just like below screenshot:-

[image]

But as i trying to add the same on "header.links" it's adding right side(near CONTACT US link).

how can i achieve my expected one?

Comment: Check the html where it rendering. It might be something related to css.

Comment: By default Magento2 added right side but i needed the same left side.

Comment: Are you working in default magento? Can you update the code which you are using to add this?

Answer (score 1):

In default.xml write below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="header.panel">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="add-new-header-link" after="store_language"> 
         <arguments>
 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Link</argument>
 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new-link</argument>
 </arguments>
     </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

I hope it's usefully for you.

Comment: this works but <li> is generated without <ul> parent. any idea how we can add li inside ul with a custom class to further style in?